# Misplaced \noalign when using xltabular

Tags: tables, xltabular

I'm creating a dynamic PDF creator using Node and LaTeX, compiling with pdflatex (pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20).

The problem is that I am attempting to create a dynamic sized table, that can \pagebreak when it overflows the footer, I tried using a lot of table packages such as `longtable`, `longtabu`, `tabularx`, etc.. but I always run into a trouble where it shows me the following message:

```
! Misplaced \noalign.
\pagebreak ->\noalign 
                      {\ifnum `}=0\fi \@testopt {\LT@no@pgbk -}4
l.702 \end{xltabular}
```

Example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
listof=totoc,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1.5cm, top=3cm, headsep=0.5cm, footskip=0.8cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
% KOMA-Script package for header and footer
\usepackage[
manualmark,
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\textheight}{0.95\textheight}
\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{CECECE}

% header and footer
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\raisebox{0\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image}}}
\ohead{\raisebox{0\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\definecolor{primary-blue}{HTML}{00A2D7}
\definecolor{ndvi-green}{HTML}{38761d}
\definecolor{ndvi-orange}{HTML}{e69138}
\definecolor{table-header}{HTML}{83D361}

\def\infobox(#1){%
    \tcbset{
        frame code={}
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        colback=primary-blue,
        colframe=white,
        colupper=white,
        width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
        enlarge left by=0mm,
        boxsep=5pt,
        arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
        halign = center
    }
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \normalfont\textbf{\large #1}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    \cfoot{
        \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}
        \infobox(\textit{RANDOM})
    }

    \newpage
    \infobox(\textbf{TEXT 1\\TEXT 2 (TEXT 3)})
    
    \centering{
        TEXT EXPLAINING WHAT THE TABLE MEANS.
    }
    
    \begin{xltabular}{0.7\linewidth}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{table-header}
        {\cellcolor{table-header}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{COL 1}}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{COL 2}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{COL 3}}
        \\ \hline
        
        
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
            
    \end{xltabular}%
\end{document}
```

The weirdest thing is: my .tex DOES GENERATE a PDF file, but it also crashes with the Misplaced error
[image]

*EDIT 1*: providing a better example of my code so we can figure out the problem

Comment: @DavidCarlisle updated my example, hope its more useful now

Comment: thanks for updaing the example  I can reproduce the error, I deleted previous comments

Comment: meanwhile `\centering{
        TEXT EXPLAINING WHAT THE TABLE MEANS.
    }` applies centering to everything, the braces are doing nothing there.

Comment: should I use \begin{center} to center only this text then? (yes I am new to TeX in general)... also, when I compile the same code through TeXStudio it works just fine (using pdflatex compiler), but on the CLI it throws the error, don't know if this information adds on anything, but...

Comment: no it isn' working in texstudio it's just hiding the error messages.

Comment: my original close vote was before you added the example not sure why people closed it after you added the example and I answered, I have voted to re-open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Missing character: There is no l in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no f in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no t in font nullfont!

LaTeX Warning: Reference `LastPage' on page 1 undefined on input line 125.

! Misplaced \noalign.
\pagebreak ->\noalign 
                      {\ifnum `}=0\fi \@testopt {\LT@no@pgbk -}4
l.125     \end{xltabular}
                         %
```

The character warnings ar due to a missing comma before `left`, the main error is showing longtable's `\\`  defiiion happening ouside a table, the tcolorbox code mus b running it spmewhere in the page foot, as her can't actually be a page break inside th infobox I just locally defind `\pagebreak` to do nothing.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
listof=totoc,
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{margin=1.5cm, top=3cm, headsep=0.5cm, footskip=0.8cm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lastpage}
% KOMA-Script package for header and footer
\usepackage[
manualmark,
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{tikz}

\setlength{\textheight}{0.95\textheight}
\setlength\extrarowheight{0pt}
\arrayrulecolor[HTML]{CECECE}

% header and footer
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\raisebox{0\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=4.5cm]{example-image}}}
\ohead{\raisebox{0\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\definecolor{primary-blue}{HTML}{00A2D7}
\definecolor{ndvi-green}{HTML}{38761d}
\definecolor{ndvi-orange}{HTML}{e69138}
\definecolor{table-header}{HTML}{83D361}

\def\infobox(#1){% why the weird non standard () syntax???
    \tcbset{
        frame code={},
        left=0pt,
        right=0pt,
        top=0pt,
        bottom=0pt,
        colback=primary-blue,
        colframe=white,
        colupper=white,
        width=\dimexpr\textwidth\relax,
        enlarge left by=0mm,
        boxsep=5pt,
        arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
        halign = center
    }
    \begin{tcolorbox}
        \normalfont\textbf{\large #1}
    \end{tcolorbox}
}

\begin{document}
    \cfoot{%%%
        \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}%%%
        \renewcommand\pagebreak[1][]{}%%%
        \infobox(\textit{RANDOM})%%%
    }

    \newpage
    \infobox(\textbf{TEXT 1TEXT 2 (TEXT 3)})
    
   
    \begin{center}
        TEXT EXPLAINING WHAT THE TABLE MEANS.
    \end{center}
      
    
    
    \begin{xltabular}{0.7\linewidth}{|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \rowcolor{table-header}
        {\cellcolor{table-header}{\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{COL 1}}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{COL 2}} & {\color[HTML]{FFFFFF} \textbf{COL 3}}
        \\ \hline
        
        
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline
        DATA 1 & DATA 2 & DATA 3 \\ \hline  
            
    \end{xltabular}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: it actually compiled this time, i think that fixed it... thanks! but a [0] showed up the side of this cfoot